# How to generalize this proof of the closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, closed-graph

I found this tricky new proof of the closed graph theorem for a Hilbert space $H$.
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02600.pdf

It says in the abstract, that it's possible to extend the proof to Banach space. But I wasn't able to do so. The problem was proving Theorem 3.

**Theorem 3.** If $A$ is a linear closed operator with $D(A) = H$, then $D(A^∗) = H$.

In the case of Banach spaces I did not find a way to prove that adjoint $A^*$ is densely deﬁned. But even if I did  - the next problem would have been to deduce that there is a weekly convergent subsequence of $A^* v_n$.

Is there another way to prove Theorem 3?